# If one test case fail,then app should not stop further testing in android espresso

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I want to check the alert message text at login time if someone enters wrong credential then alert message will show.In my test cases i have check the alert message if its wrong or right.But somehow,if the text in test cases will be "Invali Email" and alert show "Invalid email id" then the app should not stop testing another cases.What i meant is it should resume or something do,which do not effect further cases

```
if(!emailValidator(editText.getText().toString())){
                buttonlogin.click();
                UiObject notice_message = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.vastedge.priceguide:id/notcicemesage"));
                assertEquals("Invalid email",notice_message.getText().toString());
                onView(withId(R.id.ok)).perform(click());
            }
```

Comment: Where is this code snippet used, as the body of one of the tests, or as a common testing function? Also, though I understand what you want to accomplish, can you provide an example of one or more of your test case class?

Comment: so you want that each test case starts out with the app like it is newly installed? (or some other initial state that is equal for each test case, independent if a previous test succeeds or fails?)

Comment: Let me explain with an example,suppose i have a login screen containing email and password.For email validation i have made cases like if some one does not enter anything,then on login button click message will be "empty email" and if some one enters abc@ in email then "invalid email" message will show.And in the above example i have check that message text.Some how if text does not match then it should go for another cases,but what it does is stop the app.Now i hope u understand

Comment: Have you pressed the top left button of the run tab while executing an espresso test? The one with the "OK" message. This way when you launch multiple tests you can see the result of each test

Comment: hi jeprubio,can u plz elaborate your answer?I am not getting which button you are talking about?